# Visual Studio 2017 Setup Project - .NET 4 prerequisite

Tags: .net, setup-project, setup-deployment

I have a project which uses .NET 4 (for compatibility with Windows XP to 10) however in the Setup Project Prerequsites it is not availalbe to select. .NET 4 is already added as a depedency to the setup project. The project previously had .NET 4 Client Profile selected.

[image]

Comment: What does it say when you mouse hover on the exclamation? You should see some explanation, such as "prerequisite not found for bootstrapping".

Comment: Not found, but that is for Client Profile (which was previously selected). I would like .NET 4.0 full.